# JSF2 h:inputText bean Default Value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Simple question really. I have a form with a number of h:inputText fields and I require them to have a default value, but I am not sure how this is done since they are linked to a managed bean: `<h:inputText value="#{bean.instance}"/>`

I am thinking that I will probably need to link it to a properties file and then surround with an if block? Otherwise some form of Javascript implementation?

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving the properties/attributes default values in the bean constructor?

Comment: These values are to be used over multiple xhtml pages so I though if I give it default value in the constructor & someone changes the value in the inputText it always reverts back to the default value?

Comment: Perhaps you're just doing something wrong. Presetting them in bean's (post)constructor should really do it.